Custom LWC login form on Experience site not navigating after successful login
I have a custom LWC login form created. But upon successful login I am not able to navigate the logged in user to the site page. I am really not sure whether this is done on the settings page of the experience cloud or through cloud. The way I have tried it is through code which is not working as expected. This is what I get after a successful login -

Here is my code -
JS Login button click method-
 handleClick(event) {
        if (this.username && this.password) {
            event.preventDefault();
            login({ username: this.username, password: this.password })
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log('Login result: ' + result);
                    console.log('SITE_URL: ' + SITE_URL);
                    window.location.href = SITE_URL;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    alert(error);
                });
        }
    }

Printing the result appends a lot characters after the actual site name. The SITE_URL is a custom label where I have set the site url.
Here is the apex it is calling -
@AuraEnabled
public static String login(String username, String password) {
    String result = null;
    try {
        ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, '');
        result = (lgn != null) ? lgn.getUrl() : null;
        System.debug('URL-'+lgn.getUrl());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = ex.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
}


https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation

why are you navigating to hardcoded label? You should navigate to result coming from apex.

I was able to finally figure it out. It was simple -
Here is the code -
First you have to import -
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

Then you extend your class -
export default class VendorPortalLoginFormComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)

On click of a button -
handleClick(event) {
    if (this.isUsernamePasswordEnabled) {
        if (this.username && this.password) {
            event.preventDefault();
            login({ username: this.username, password: this.password })
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result.isLoggedIn) {
                  
                        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                            type: 'comm__namedPage',
                            attributes: {
                                name: 'work_orders_page__c'
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        this.errorMessage = result.message;
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    alert(error);
                });
        }
    }
}

